# multiple url connections in java code

Tags: java, url, connection

I have a following function that is called multiple times with

```
report="http://myURL/some_file.php" + "?someParam=" + getSomeParam()";
```

where `myURL` is always the same and `some_file.php` and `someParam` are different each time.

```
private static void makeReport(final String report) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(report);
        try {
            url.openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return; // do nothing
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return; // do nothing
    }
}
```

the question is, if it is an efficient way to handle this situation, each time opening
new connection with different parameters? Also, reports have no effect on main program, 
so should it be done in different thread/process?

Comment: You can avoid the inner try/catch if you just try and define the URL in a first try block and return if it fails to parse.

Comment: Also, where do you `.close()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is some overhead to opening a new connection, but it doesn't sound like your program makes extensive use of sockets, so the overhead should be negligible. You don't need two try blocks, by the way, you can just have one and put the catch blocks one after the other.

```
private static void makeReport(final String report) {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(report);
        in = url.openStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return; // do nothing
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return; // do nothing
    } finally {
        try { in.close(); } catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

As for whether this method should go in its own thread, depends on the context. Does it need to be asynchronous? For what it's worth, it shouldn't take too long to make a simple GET request. I can't imagine a situation where you would need it to be in its own thread.

As a last note, whenever you open a connection it's always a good practice to close it, especially in a try-catch-finally (or try-with-resources) construct. Not following this practice is a great way to introduce connection leaks in more complex socket programming.

Comment: This won't work as you think it does, since `MalformedURLException` extends `IOException`. The second `catch` block will never be processed.

Comment: Hmmm, now, if the URL fails to parse, `in` will be null in the `finally` block ;)

Comment: fge/Ryan Stewart - yeah, I often resort to a try-catch within the finally block, at least for Java 6. It's ugly but it gets the job done. With Java 7 there's try-with-resources, which was made for this scenario.